# Gradle: "apply from" gets evaluated before the rest of the script?

Tags: gradle

I have multi-project script with multiple components/JARs. 
Each child script/project defines componentTitle:

```
ext {
    componentTitle = 'Application1'
}

apply from: '../war/gradle/component.gradle'
```

The shared code is in component.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': componentTitle    }
}
```

I am getting error:

A problem occurred evaluating script.

> The value of a manifest attribute must not be null.

This means that componentTitle is not defined by the time the child script is evaluated. The componentTitle definition is before "apply from" statement.

Comment: Have you confirmed the path is correct and that Gradle is finding *component.gradle*?

Comment: Yes, Gradle is finding component.gradle.

Answer (score 2):

The applied script gets evaluated exactly at the point of `apply from: ...` (easy to confirm by adding some `println`s). There must be some other problem. One thing you can try is to replace `'Implementation-Title': componentTitle` with `'Implementation-Title': project.componentTitle`, although it shouldn't make a difference.